# What is difference between async methods with Task and without?

Tags: c#, async-await

What is the key differences between those two methods?

First method that use `Task<TResult>`:

```
public async Task GetTaskDataFromAPI()
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://fakeapi/users"))
                {
                    string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine(apiResponse);
                }
            }
        }
```

And second method that use simple `void`:

```
public async void GetVoidDataFromAPI()
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://fakeapi/users"))
                {
                    string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine(apiResponse);
                }
            }
        }
```

I can't notice the difference when I'm debugging this code. Why and when those methods should be used and what is the main differences between them?

Comment: Basically, don't do that unless you have a good reason to do that

Answer (score 1):

The difference is simple: you cannot `await` the `async void` version.

If you call this function, how do you know when it's finished to queue something after it? You can only run other code *at the same time* as the continuation inside your `GetVoidDataFromAPI` (ie during the `GetAsync` call).